How To Fix Busybox Initramfs Error permanently
I am getting a boot failure with message
failure: file system check of the root filesystem failed
the root filesystem on /dev/sda5 requires a manual fsck 
busybox v1.30.1 (ubuntu 1:1.30.1-4ubuntu6.4) built-in shell (ash) 
enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

The problem is I have used all the fsck methods I've found here and I got it to boot normally
But the moment I open an application like Chrome and then try to reboot later on
I get meet with the same error
I want to fix this permanently
Is there a way ?
Or is my hard drive corrupt ?

Use your drive's SMART to check health (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools) but you may also have caused corruption to your (20.04?) system by installing packages built for another release that can also cause corruption leading to this (let alone incomplete shutdowns or other user behavior).

In initramfs prompt type : fsck /dev/sda5 -y

You appear to have not found the problem, which is mandatory to fix it permanently... eg. if it's a failing disk; you cannot fix it via meta data corrections (ie. fsck etc) as they only fix the symptom of the problem & don't touch the actual problem. Data (blocks containing your data) and file-system data (filenames etc or metadata) all exist on a physical device.. if your issue is the device itself, you need to fix the device. A software config mistake (by user with sudo rights) can also corrupt data causing repeated problems... but again you need to find the cause.
